# I'm stuck on coordinate graph involving tangents of parabolas...

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections

Consider the function $f(x) = \max \{-11x - 37, x - 1, 9x + 3\}$ defined for all real $x.$ Let $p(x)$ be a quadratic polynomial tangent to the graph of $f$ at three distinct points with $x$-coordinates $x_1,$ $x_2,$ $x_3.$ Find $x_1 + x_2 + x_3.$

I have found a piecewise function representing $f(x)$, and I do not know what else to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: There’s always the brute-force approach: work out the general equation of the tangent to the parabola $y=ax^2+bx+c$ and use that to find the equation of the unique parabola determined by these three tangent lines. Finally, work out the intersections of the parabola with the three lines.

Comment: I tried that, but I cannot find a system to find the equation of the parabola.

Comment: Write the equation of the tangent to $y=ax^2+bx+c$ at an arbitrary point and compare coefficients. However, you don’t need to find the equation of the parabola at all. Use the “two point, two tangents” property of parabolas and the fact that its axis is parallel to the $y$-axis to generate a system of three linear equations in the $x_i$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be solved without explicitly finding the equation of the parabola. Its axis is parallel to the $y$-axis, so it is uniquely determined by the three tangent lines. Taking the first two tangent lines, we use the [two-points-two-tangents property](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#2-points-2-tangents-property) of parabolas to equate the difference in $y$-coordinates of the points of tangency with the difference in $y$-coordinates of the other intersections of the two lines with the vertical lines through those points: $$(-11x_1-37)-(x_2-1)=(x_1-1)-(-11x_2-37).$$ Applying the same construction to the other two pairs of tangent lines gives you a system of three linear equations in the $x_i$, which I hope you can solve on your own.

Comment: [+1] Very nice, indeed.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this property of parabolas. Moreover, this Wikipedia article you gave for reference is a pure marvel.

Answer (score 2):

The following image displays 3 line portions :

[image]

Let the quadratic function have equation $y=f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ with derivative $f'(x)=2ax+b$.

Assuming that the points $(x_k;f(x_k))$ of contact of the parabola are one on each line portion, one has two families of contraints : the fact that the parabola passes through the points, and the fact that, at these points, the slopes are the given slopes :

$$\begin{cases}ax_1^2+bx_1+c&=&-11x_1-37\\ax_2^2+bx_2+c&=&x_2-1\\ax_3^2+bx_3+c&=&9x_3+3\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}2ax_1+b=-11\\2ax_2+b=1\\2ax_3+b=9\end{cases}$$

which makes 6 equations with 6 unknowns.

Submitting them to a CAS (Computer Algebra system), I have directly obtained a unique solution :

> $$x_1=-9/2, \ x_2=-3/2, \ x_3=1/2, \ a=2, \ b=7, \ c=7/2$$

therefore

> $$x_1+x_2+x_3=-11/2$$

Remark : There must be a way to obtain this sum in a simpler way, but I don't see how.

---

Edit : in fact, @amd has found this way. His solution that you can see below is a jewel and IMHO should have been selected instead of mine :

For instructive purposes, here is a way to program it (with Matlab facilities for handling symbolic variables)

```
syms x1 x2 x3
f=@(x)(-11*x-37);
g=@(x)(x-1);
h=@(x)(9*x+3);
S=solve(f(x1)-g(x2)==g(x1)-f(x2),...
        f(x1)-h(x3)==h(x1)-f(x3),...
        g(x2)-h(x3)==h(x2)-g(x3),...
        x1,x2,x3);
[S.x1,S.x2,S.x3], % gives x_1=-9/2, x_2=-3/2, x_3=1/2
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to do this without calculus, as I haven't taken the course yet? I would like to see a more "elegant" solution. Thanks for the help, and I hope I get to understand the content you have presented in the future!

Comment: I will think about a non-calculus approach.

Comment: You can use the dual conic equation to generate a system of linear equations for $a$, $b$ and $c$, and then use their values to compute the poles of the three lines to get values for the $x_i$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I wouldn’t really call it a correction. It’s the same overall approach as you’ve taken, but without involving calculus.

Comment: @amd I thought afterwards to this solution, but it would be well above the level of the asker who hasn't for example done calculus (see his commentaries)

Comment: @amd ... but involving the concept of dual conic which would constitute a higher level difficulty.

Comment: I suppose that one could start with the generic tangent equation $(y-y_0)/2=axx_0+b(x+x_0)/2+c$, which can be derived without calculus.

Comment: Oops. That should be $(y+y_0)/2$ on the LHS.